# RC circuit with a constant current source

Tags: capacitor, capacitor-charging

I am trying to simulate a series RC circuit excited with a constant DC current source in LTSPICE. The expectation is that it should linearly charge the capacitor with a constant current flowing through it however what I am seeing in the simulation window is a zero or nearly zero(femto ampere) current always through the capacitor. Can you please help to understand where I am going wrong? Attaching images for my simulation.
P.S. I am using basic Capacitor in ltspice, no specific model from it's library.
[image: Circuit diagram]
[image: Transient response]

Comment: Note that if you have a current source and want to RC lowpass filter it, you can put the R and C in parallel. By Thevenin's theorem, it will be equivalent to a voltage source with series resistor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LTspice calculates the DC operating point before starting the transient simulation. If you check the capacitor voltage at the beginning of the simulation you'll probably find that it is 1GV. The capacitor voltage after a very long time would, in theory, increase without limit with a 1mA current source feeding into it and no parallel resistance, so the DC operating point makes no sense in this case.

If you name the node at the top of the capacitor Vcap and add an initial condition:
.ic V(Vcap) = 0 as a spice directive you'll get a more sensible answer.

You can also set the initial condition for currents in inductors, which is useful in the analogous situation where a voltage source is connected across an inductor (though LTspice tries to save you from this by inserting a hidden default resistance of 1m\$\Omega\$ in series with the pure inductance). But if you start off with a 1V source across an inductor you'll still end up with a constant 1000A flowing rather than the linear increase of current with time you might have been expecting.

Answer (score 8):

You need to tell LTSpice to skip the initial operating point solution:

[image]

Then you will get the graph you are expecting:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat, some of which may or may not bet better suited for when the simulation gets more complex.

You can also

- Use PULSE or PWL for the current source
- Use an arbitrary behavioural current source and make it depend on something (e.g. a DC voltage source that is somewhere anways with an appropriate behaviour)
- Even though the `startup` parameter to trans says to start external DC sources at 0V it works for this case too, because it will implicitly cause the necessary operating points to be 0V. This option often comes in handy for similar situations where you need any kind of startup situation accurately modelled.